# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

during my python learning I've got an error in this code:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, location, payment_method):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.location = location
        self.payment_method = payment_method
        self.login_attempts = 0

    def increment_login_attempts(self):
        self.login_attempts += 1

    def reset_login_attempts(self):
        self.login_attempts = 0

    def printing_login_attempts(self):
        print('Quantity of login attempts: ' + str(self.login_attempts))

    def describe_user(self):
        print('Current user first name: ' + self.first_name.title())
        print('Current user last name: ' + self.last_name.title())
        print('Location is ' + self.location.title() + '. Payment method is ' + self.payment_method)

    def greet_user(self):
        print('Hello ' + self.first_name.title() + ' ' + self.last_name.title() + '!!!')


class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, location, payment_method):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, location, payment_method)
        self.privilegis = Privilegis()


class Privilegis:
    def __init__(self, privilegis_type):
        self.privilegis_type = ['Allow to delete users', 'Allow to rename users', 'Allow to ban users']
    def show_privilegis(self):
        print('Special admins privilegis are: ' + ', '.join(self.privilegis))

new_user = Admin('John', 'Edwards', 'LA', 'visa')
new_user.privilegis.show_privilegis()
```

**error description**

```
self.privilegis = Privilegis()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'privilegis_type'
```

I cant get what the problem is. How should I use one class(Privilegis) as attribute of another(Admin) ?

Comment: Well the error is clear, you can not construct a `Priviegis` like that, you need to pass a `priveliges_type)`. Although aparently you do not use it at all.

Comment: FYI, "privileges" is spelled "privileges."

Comment: Your code reads: `class Privilegis: def __init__(self, privilegis_type):`. So yeah, the `__init__` method needs one more argument.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Privileges` class, you write:

```
class Privileges:
    def __init__(self, privilegis_type):
        self.privilegis_type = ['Allow to delete users', 'Allow to rename users', 'Allow to ban users']
    # ...
```

You thus specify that it requires a `privilegis_type` parameter, but that is strange, since later, you do nothing with that.

Either you should probably rewrite the constructor, and handle the parameter (and thus provide one when you construct a `Privilegis` object, or you should get rid of the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Admin` class has a `privilegis` attribute that initializes an instance of `Privilegis`. The `__init__()` method defines how you initialize the class, and in your case it requires a `privilegis_type` as a parameter.

If you want this privilege to pass to the `Admin` at instantiation time, add the parameter to its `__init__` method and pass that internally to the `privilege` attribute.

```
class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, location, payment_method, privilegis_type): # add privilegis type
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, location, payment_method)
        self.privilegis = Privilegis(privilegis_type) # pass that privilegis type, needed by the Privilegis class


class Privilegis:
    def __init__(self, privilegis_type):
        self.privilegis_type = ['Allow to delete users', 'Allow to rename users', 'Allow to ban users']
    def show_privilegis(self):
        print('Special admins privilegis are: ' + ', '.join(self.privilegis_type)) # fixed that also
```

although in your code there are two major errors:

- the `Privilegis` class is not using the parameter at all. You could maintain your original code, and **remove** the `privilegis_type` *or* **use a sane default**, which will depend on what you are trying to do.
- `self.privilegis` is not defined anywhere inside `Privilegis`. I believe you want it to be `self.privilegis_type`

this means having something like this:

```
class Privilegis:
        def __init__(self, privilegis_type=None): # could be anything
            self.privilegis_type = ['Allow to delete users', 'Allow to rename users', 'Allow to ban users']
        def show_privilegis(self):
            print('Special admins privilegis are: ' + ', '.join(self.privilegis_type)) # fixed that also
```